# How do I export subsets of a column-split?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to export two subsets of a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(factor = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), var = "value")

df
  factor   var
1      A value
2      A value
3      B value
4      B value
```

I split the data frame by factor using `group_split()` but can't seem to export the resulting subsets as `.csv`. These subsets should both have variable names:

```
dfa
  factor   var
1      A value
2      A value

dfb
  factor   var
1      B value
2      B value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `split` and then use `imap`.  `split` gives the `list` with names of the 'factor' `levels` and using `imap`, the `.y` will get the name of each of the `list` elements, which can be `paste`d (`str_c` -  does the same thing, but with more checks)

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
split(df, df$factor) %>%
   imap(~ write.csv(.x, file = str_c('df', .y, '.csv'), quote = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` to loop over the list of `dataframes` created by `group_split`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_split(factor) %>% 
  sapply(., function (x) 
              write.csv(x, file=paste0("df", unique(x$factor), ".csv")))
```

Answer (score 0):

can you do:

```
dfa = df[df$factor == "A",]

dfb = df[df$factor == "B",]

write.csv(dfa,"Name Out A.csv")

write.csv(dfb,"Name Out B.csv")
```